# HTML img and ASP.NET Image and relative paths

Tags: asp.net, image, relative-path

What is the correct way to reference an image in ASP.NET for live deployment on IIS?

The following works in dev and production:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibnEdit" runat="server" OnClick="ibnEdit_Click" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/images/one.png" Visible="false" ToolTip="Edit" />
```

The following doesn't work in either: (why not?)

```
<img src="~/App_Themes/Default/images/two.gif" />
```

The following works in dev but not in production:

```
<img src="../App_Themes/Default/images/two.gif" />
```

Comment: Are you sure you images are deployed in production?

Comment: @are the images in the same path as dev environment.??

Answer (score 28):

If you want to use a regular `img` tag with the `~` path, you can just add `runat="server"` into the tag as an attribute (like regular server controls) and the path will be resolved. e.g:

```
<img src="~/App_Themes/Default/images/two.gif" runat="server" />
```

For your second part, is the ../ image reference appearing on more than one page, for example a user control or master page (etc) such that you might be using it at different folder levels...

Comment: Nice, does it have any effect on overall performance of website?

Comment: @Tanveer it should essentially have no effect. The control would go through the control life cycle. That being said, you would probably need to add a LOT of images to see any difference.

Answer (score 6):

I use this syntax for access images from master pages

```
<img src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Content/Images/error_img.jp")%>" width="350" style="padding-right: 15px; padding-top: 20px;"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

The ~ will only work on a server control such as `<asp:Image>` or `<asp:ImageButton>`. This tells ASP.Net to insert the application path. Sometime that's just `"/"` but if your application is not the root directory of the website it will include the path it is in. The `img` tag is just html and it will not be altered by ASP.Net, so the browser gets the path `"~/App_Themes/Default/images/two.gif"` and doesn't know how to read it.

I don't know why the last example works in dev but not in production. It might has something to do with having the application in the root directory in dev but in a sub directory in production.

Comment: +1, also, @mmmbop, to resolve ~/ in a HTML tag you can use the UrlHelper class (instead of switching to using asp:image controls)  `<img src="<%= Url.Content("~/App_Themes/Default/images/two.gif") %>" />`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

$(".selector").attr('src', "Content/themes/base/images/img.png");

The important is that you do not have "/" at the beginning of your new src.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] imageArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Upload_Image.png"));

string base64ImageRepresentation = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look into my answer . I have resolved the issue using C# language.
[Why can't I do <img src="C:/localfile.jpg">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090712/why-cant-i-do-img-src-c-localfile-jpg/62932468#62932468)