# Could not open file through web page which is under subfolder under root directory in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, subdirectory, asp.net-webpages

I have one issue in my webpage. Actually I have developed asp.net 3.5 website. I have created a webpage named **HR.aspx** under Sub Directory in my project root directory.

```
Webpage Location


     (ProjectName) >> Department (Subfolder) >> HR (Subfolder) >> HR.aspx
```

and I have the code in this file to open a file like pdf.

My file location folder is under my project.

```
File Location


 (ProjectName) >> SIPL (SubFolder) >> Department (Subfolder) >> HR (Subfolder) >> HR.pdf
```

My issue is when I put the HR.aspx page under root directory the file is opening successfully and when I put this page under subfolder (as shown above) it not opening and showing file not found error. I think page not find the path of the file because it is in subfolder. How to overcome this issue. Please help.

Comment: am i wron but the right way to show local files is this way
file://c:\bla.jpg And be sure this only works local (client side)

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
<pre>
    <img src="\Images\Open.jpg"/>
</pre>
```

To use a file in you web application. You should have a folder in your application.
Say you have a folder **Images** at your root directory.
Then you should use the relative path of you image.
More Details
[HTML img and ASP.NET Image and relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190769/html-img-and-asp-net-image-and-relative-paths)

### Edit 1

Since you have written

```
<img src="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Open.jpg"/>
```

which is wrong for the web application.

If you write like above the browser will look for the local system file.
Rather than file on the application-server.

Answer (score 0):

please relative path to  select the image . So first copy the image in any of your project solution folder and refer like:

```
<img src='\NewFolderName\Open.jpg'/>
```