# I make fileUpload to save images in folder now i want to display it

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

That is the code to get url of image from the folder

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptImages" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <img alt="" style='height: 75px; width: 75px' src='<%# Eval("Images") %>' />

        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This do display images

```
string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images"));
List<String> images = new List<string>(filesindirectory.Count());

foreach (string item in filesindirectory)
{
    images.Add(String.Format("~/Images/{0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item)));
}

rptImages.DataSource = images;
rptImages.DataBind();
```

when i run it it says:" An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. "

and show :( `List<String> images = new List<string>(filesindirectory.Count());`) in red

What should i do?

Comment: check if this [post from SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817870/asp-net-strange-compilation-error) is helpful to you?

Comment: Still does not work

Comment: `Server.MapPath("~")` returns the physical path to the root of the application. Does your Images folder exist on this route path?

Comment: When i upload the image go to the file but it does not appear

Comment: @sagar the images in the folder and folder there too

Answer (score 0):

I have not encountered error you mentioned, but I found another error on the binding.

Here you should change the binding using `Container.DataItem` and since you are using `~` for the path you should add runat="server" like mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190769/html-img-and-asp-net-image-and-relative-paths).

```
<img alt="" style='height: 75px; width: 75px' src='<%# Container.DataItem %>' runat="server"/>
```

Comment: The same Error.
That is Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'List' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)