# My logo will not show up in bootstrap3 navbar from saved images in Visual Studio. Only images that appear are from web urls

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, visual-studio-2017, href, navbar

I am trying to get a logo image to appear in my bootstrap3 Navbar in Visual Studio but it won't appear. For some reason though if I use a image that contains a web url it works fine no matter the height and width of the image. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**Code I'm using that won't work:**

```
     <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                      </button>

                      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                          <img id="logo" src="Images/logo.png" /></a>
                    </div>
```

The image appears however in my split view on Visual studio but when I run the page in Chrome or IE I get the broken image symbol.

**Code that does work with an image url:**

```
    <div class="navbar-header">
                      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                      </button>

                      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                          <img id="logo" src="http://www.kyste.org/userfiles/2/kyste2013/S&SC_logo.png" /></a>
                    </div>
```

**The folder path is correct as well as I am using images in a carousel that appear fine for example in the below.**

```
    <asp:Image ID="imgPaintball" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/paintball.jpg" alt="Paintball"/>
```

I am completely lost to what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Can we see a live working example?

Comment: @David how would I show a live working example?

Comment: Try adding a forward slash to the start of your path like so: `<img id="logo" scr="/Images/logo.png" >`

Comment: That's done it, thanks a mill!

Comment: Please accept it if it has helped you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case; try adding a slash to your `img` path.

```
<img id="logo" src="/Images/logo.png" >
```

For the record, by the by, you do not need to close your `img` tags with a `/`. They are just there to make it easier to read. They do nothing!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the forward slash worked this time only because the relative link happened to be correct. Try adding an image in a page or control in a different directory and it will probably break also. You need to resolve your image links from the root using either `ResolveUrl("~/Images/logo.png")` or as follows:

```
<img id="logo" src="~/Images/logo.png" runat="server" />
```

[More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874636/what-is-the-difference-between-resolveurl-and-resolveclienturl) [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190769/html-img-and-asp-net-image-and-relative-paths)