# <img> tag not showing the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `img` tag with `src = "file:///C:/Users/king/Documents/testing.jpg"`. This tag is not showing the image . Whats the problem ?

Comment: Did you tried to quote a path?

Comment: I guess the image is not loaded, did you try to set an "alt" test and see if it appears ?

Comment: you should provide more context, and a real excerpt from your HTML.

Comment: Related? [Why can't I do <img src=“C:/localfile.jpg”>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090712/why-cant-i-do-img-src-c-localfile-jpg)

Answer (score 3):

`img` tag doesn't have a `href` attribute.. that's for links.

- Use `src="image path here"` instead. The full tag is `<img src="path" alt="alt text" />`
- Make sure the path leads to a valid file
- Put the path in quotes
- Know that it will display a file from your computer and this will only work if the HTML page is locally stored on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be arising because the address that you have goes to a file on your computer. If someone else is trying to access this page from a webserver, they most likely will not have your file at that same location on their computer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="file:///C:/Users/King/Documents/testing.jpg"><img src="file:///C:/Users/King/Documents/testing.jpg" /></a>
```

Must work

Be sure if testing.jpg is there.. Maybe is testing.JPG ..

Answer (score 0):

`<img src="FILE">` is the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

`<img src="path/to/file.jpg" alt="This is my image" />`is a correct tag...try that instead
And you cant use a local path like that, it goes to a file on your harddrive, nobody else can access it if you put it online. Use a relative link instead like "rootfolder/images/yourimage.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Due to security reasons, I'm not sure if a browswer can always access a protocol of file:// are you running on localhost?  If not that is your reason.  I would advise you to always use relational URLS if possible so if your HTML is in Documents then src="testing.jpg" would be fine.

In general I would recommend having the images in a subfolder of where your index file is to make it easier and to allow relative urls such as "./images/testing.jpg" or "../images/testing.jpg".

Answer (score 0):

use relative paths as opposed to absolute for example if the image file was to folders above where the place you are storing your webpage at use ../../testing.jpg