# firefox image loading issue

Tags: html, firefox, css, xhtml

i loaded an image from my desktop
its loading properly in the chrome but its not loading in the firefox 
providing by image tag code below
the problem is in this line

```
<img alt="Splitwise" id="logo" src="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\defie.bmp">
```

code:

```
        <header>

<body>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->


        <img alt="Splitwise" id="logo" src="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\defie.bmp">
        <header>
            <div class="menu">

                 <!--<a href="/">
                    <img alt="Splitwise" id="logo" src="//dx0qysuen8cbs.cloudfront.net/assets/logo-ffe4f2b804af3331e58f523445a844e2.png">
                </a>-->
                <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <div class="clearFloat"></div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
        <script>
            var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']];
            (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
            g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Why is the image on the C:\ drive?

Comment: Relevant.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090712/why-cant-i-do-img-src-c-localfile-jpg

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
<img alt="Splitwise" id="logo" src="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\defie.bmp">
```

to

```
<img alt="Splitwise" id="logo" src="file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/defie.bmp">
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it's because you are using back slash try a uri path with foward slash:

```
<img src="images/image.bmp" alt="whatever">
```

if that doesn't work try

```
<img src="file://C:/your_path_to_pic.jpeg" alt="whatever">
```

Answer (score 0):

1st of all drive images dont load on a ftp server you will need to upload them to a file map on the ftp use it like

```
<img src="LINK" alt="ALT TXT" />
```

Try replacing // with the complete and valid link, because the path that you have submitted isnt valid. try this line :

```
<img src="http://www.dx0qysuen8cbs.cloudfront.net/assets/logo-ffe4f2b804af3331e58f523445a844e2.png" alt="Splitwise" id="logo">
```

Answer (score 0):

Resources are referenced within the same directory as your served file. Say this code file is called page.html.. referencing a path like "C:..", will look for a C folder within the same folder that page.html is in. You can use "../" to go back one folder (to the parent folder).

If the page is being served by a server (not sure what happens if it's not), you can use prepend the url with a `/` to use a relative path from the root directory of the web site/applcation.

If you put the image file in the same directory as page.html, you can just use

```
<img alt="Splitwise" id="logo" src="defie.bmp">
```

Or, for example, if you place it in a sub-directory (dir1) of the one that page.html is in..

```
<img alt="Splitwise" id="logo" src="dir1/defie.bmp">
```