# ASP.Net MVC image not displaying

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, image

I have a view with the following -

```
<img src= "@Url.Content(new Uri(image.Path).AbsoluteUri)" alt="@(new Uri(image.Path).AbsoluteUri)" />
```

`image.Path` is a string

It renders the below html

```
<img alt="file:///C:/Users/Tom/MyAppApp_Data/uploads/myImage.jpg" src="file:///C:/Users/Tom/MyAppApp_Data/uploads/myImage.jpg">
```

**But** the image is not displayed in the browser.

If I open FireBug and hover over the image element, the image will show in the FireBug window.

If I take the above html and place in a `test.html` file and open the file in a browser, the image is displayed.

However, if I hard code the above html into my view, it does **NOT** work!

**UPDATE 1**

If I save the page in Firefox, the image is downloaded and when I open the html file the image is displayed.

This is beginning to sound like an IIS Express problem.

**UPDATE 2**

If I look at the view in the Page Inspector the images show up as expected!

Comment: `image.Path`  is a string

Comment: why do you need absolute uri? just use `~`?

Comment: Sure, what is it exactly?  Is it a relative path to an image in your MVC project?

Comment: @BhushanFirake the location of the file is coming from the database. It may not be withing the app data always

Comment: @MikeC it is the full path to the image in the form C:\Users\Tom\...

Comment: What browser? It's probably security zone related i.e. a page served from a server is attempting to access a local file system file.

Comment: @Plymouth223 problem in Firefox, Chrome and IE

Comment: @tom In IE, try putting the site into your Trusted sites security zone and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that this is not possible. Imagine if any web page could navigate your folder structure and check files out. Browsers won't let you do this so maybe you could expose your images by a service on the client.

The answer by @bjorn tipling gives you some ideas of what you could do for a work around and confirms my understanding.

[Why can't I do <img src="C:/localfile.jpg">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090712/why-cant-i-do-img-src-c-localfile-jpg)

Comment: ah, so my I should store my images in a directory that is served my a website, then I could use the url to the files there.

Comment: That^ would work for sure. The reason your page inspector shows the image is because it is running locally and won't see an issue if a local web page is accessing local resources.