# Generate picture gallery from text file

Tags: php, html

I have a text file with 10 paths to files saved on my server, that looks like this:

```
C:\pictures\123.jpg
C:\pictures\124.jpg
C:\pictures\125.jpg
```

I'd like to show the pictures from the text file on a website. I can't directly put the links into a php script because the file is dynamically generated and has different paths everytime.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? We won't write your code

Comment: Read/open file, then `foreach($files as $image){...}` and `glob()` is also an option.

Comment: I don't want you to write my code, I just don't know how to approach the whole thing.

Comment: @MonaccoFranze Use `file()` and `foreach()`

Comment: With `glob()`, you can filter out images if you also have `.png` files, but don't want to show them. Again, it's an option and can be done with your existing text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here i use [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to get all lines of the file in an array. After this i simple loop through them and print it as an image path)

```
<?php

    $lines = file("test.txt");

    foreach($lines as $line)
        echo "<img src='" . trim($line) . "'>";

?>
```

Comment: Nice :) check out my answer too !

Comment: @MonaccoFranze You're welcome! Glade that i could help you :D

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I have one last question. When i run the script, I don't see anything, butIn the source code, everything is as it should be. "<img src='C:/Users/Server/Pictures/pic123.JPG'>" I have modified the script to add <p> and </p> to every path, but they still don't show up. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong? I'll try to fix it as far as I can by myself.

Comment: When I paste the echo'ed sourcecode from the page into a seperate php file and open it, it works. I guess that's just the way to go?

Comment: @MonaccoFranze This would only work for you. You have to use a path from your server. (e.g. `../../path/image.png`)

Comment: I now put the images in my htdocs folder and changed the paths accordingly, but the pictures still won't show up. After I execute the php, i still get a blank page with source code looking like this:
"<p><img src='C:/xampp/htdocs/DATABASE_PICTURES/P123.JPG'></p>

It's not about user rights, because I can access the files directly (via link on server) from my other computer.

Comment: @MonaccoFranze Where is your script in `htdocs` located? (Also for your information why you can't do this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4090712/3933332) And if your script is located e.g. in `htdocs/xy/` then your path has to be: `../DATABASE_PICTURES/P123.JPG`

Comment: It's in the main htdocs folder. I modified the script to fit my paths :

<?php

    $lines = file("C:/xampp/htdocs/results/result.csv");

    foreach($lines as $line)
        echo "<p><img src='" . trim($line) . "'></p>";

?>

Comment: @MonaccoFranze Okay if your script is in the root folder use this: `$lines = file("results/result.csv");` And for the paths use this: `DATABASE_PICTURES/P123.JPG` and so on

Comment: That did the trick, thank you for taking the time! If you pm me your paypal adress, I'll  treat you to a beer (except if you are from Denmark, then half a beer has to do it)

Comment: @MonaccoFranze Nice, i'm happy that i could help you :D This is better then a beer

Comment: @MonaccoFranze Canadian beer is apparently just as strong ;-) but I for one don't touch the stuff, but a double Espress would be nice. *Cheers!*

Comment: @MonaccoFranze One thing though. Seeing `C:/xampp/htdocs/DATABASE_PICTURES/` if you're using your text file with what seems to be DB-related, why use a text file in the first place; why not just use a DB exclusively? It's a lot less work than a text file and you'd need to protect that text file through `.htaccess` and not let anyone get a hold of it.

Comment: The text file gets automatically generated by a software that biometrically compares  pictures, it contains the path and a percentage value. I then automatically sort the rows according to the percentage value, then cut the values out and also cut out the unnecessary parts of the path.(with a script)

I thought about using a database, but as I have no experience at all with sql or anything like that, I'll stick with this method for now. When my prototype is running exactly as i want it to, i might switch.

Comment: @MonaccoFranze I understand. I too used to work with text files about 3-4 years ago, till I dived into and took the initiative to learn SQL. Once you've gotten a good grasp of it, you'd of wanted to have learned it a long time ago; as I did also ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try and draw a neat table of images from your file .

*NOTE: I am assuming all your files in the folder are images.*

```
$root = 'C:\pictures';
$files = scandir( $directory );
echo '<table>';
foreach( $files as $file )
{
    if(is_file($file))
    {
        echo '<tr><td><img src="' . $root . $file . '" /></td><td>' . $file . '</td></tr>';
    }
}
echo '</table>
```

*Let me know if I helped :)*

Comment: Sure, this would work, but the idea is to read from a file and not from a folder. *"I'd like to show the pictures from the text file on a website."*

Answer (score 0):

I don't have opportunity to test this. But I hope this help.

```
$handle = fopen("images.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($pathToImg = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        echo "<img src='".$pathToImg."'/>";
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```