# jquery how to add image from computer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am working on a website and creating my own gallery.
However there seems to be a little problem with the code.
i wanna add my picture from my computer so it has the right width and heihgt.
here is the code.I tried to do cover in css but some images are too big and wont fit.Thank you for reading.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#button1').click(function()
{
$('#gallery').css("background-image", 'src=C:\Users\Eigenaar\Desktop\Nieuwe map\luffy');
 //luffy serieuse kop
});  </script>
```

and this is my second button wich works perfectly fine but also wanna change because width and height problems

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#button2').click(function()
{
$('#gallery').css("background-image", "url(http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/mvl/images/e/e9/Luffy-One-Piece.png/revision/latest?cb=20140221162732");
//luffy lachende kop
});  </script>
```

so what i wanna know is how to add my own picture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I do <img src="C:/localfile.jpg">?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090712/why-cant-i-do-img-src-c-localfile-jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image path you use shouldn't be the actual path of the image on your computer, it should be the path that the specific html file you're in would use to get to the image.

Your link here is the problem:

```
'src=C:\Users\Eigenaar\Desktop\Nieuwe map\luffy'
```

For example, if I had a directory that contained:

```
index.html

img.jpg
```

`index.html` could display `img.jpg` using `src='img.jpg'`.

However, imagine I have a directory where index.html is on the same level as a directory called "images" which contains your image file, like this:

```
index.html

images
    img.jpg
```

Then, in order to display the image I would use `src='images/img.jpg'`.

Most of the time, people have a folder with all of their website images in the same folder as their index.html file so they can pull directly from the folder.

Hope this helps!

*Bonus learning note*:

`..` means "go up a directory". This is useful if you can't directly access the images folder from your html file. For example, if your directories looked like this:

```
html
  index.html

images
  img.jpg
```

You would first have to go up a directory before entering the `images` folder and displaying `img.jpg`. Then, your file path would be `src='../images/img.jpg'`.

Comment: i tried everything out i possibly could with this but my english ain't the best.so ur telling me i should make an folder for images and than use     src = '\images\luffy.jpg or what?