# IMG src='file//..' does not return expected image BUT the same file//.. in navigation bar does

Tags: html

I'm developing a page that uses an image from a Networked File System.

The HTML is:

```
    <img src='file://192.168.1.25/dir/subdir/fname.jpg'/>
```

and the image does not display.

However when I put

```
    file://192.168.1.25/dir/subdir/fname.jpg
```

directly in the Navigation Bar the image displays with no problem.

I've already researched the problem and saw a lot of answers about slashes (the number of them and type - forward or backward) and also some bizarre suggestions but no definitive answer that works. I'm sure there must be a very simple solution. If I can display the image perfectly from the Nav Bar, I can't see any reason why the img src= would behave differently (but then browser developers may be strange beasts and they certainly all do it a different way).

I suppose that an http://... link in the src= would work fine but I was trying to avoid mounting a Web Server on the source machine just for this purpose as the Web App is destined to be an internal web where all the authorized users will have access to the Networked File share and the source machine is destined to be in an externally available environment with various daemons handling all external client communications and other tasks.

I'm testing with Chrome right now and have not tried it on other browsers but I really need a portable solution that would work on MOST if not ALL HTML5 browsers.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I do <img src="C:/localfile.jpg">?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090712/why-cant-i-do-img-src-c-localfile-jpg)

Comment: Not really a duplicate but the virtual directory suggestion does work ( only if I put the Context element in the Host section of Tomcat's server.xml - I couldn't get it to work any other way). I thought there should be an answer in HTML realm as the browser displays the image fine from the Nav Bar but not in the SRC=. Anyway thanks for the additional info and I believe this is a more portable solution anyway. Thanks again..