# In HTML, how can I build a file picker that can change the image displayed without using action listener?

Tags: javascript, html

This is what I have in HTML:

```
<img src="images/defaultProfile.jpg" id="image">
<input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" id="imgPath">
<input type="submit" onclick="uploadImg()">
```

The image with an id of "image" automatically loads a default image from a designated directory by default. Then, the user can I pick an image from the file picker. When the user hits the submit button written on the last line, The `uploadImg()` written on javaScript file will get the image from input and change the image displayed.

But, my question is how I can enable the user to change the image by just picking a image file from the directory without hitting the "submit" button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `change` listener to the image input:

```js
document.querySelector('#imgPath').onchange = () => {
  console.log('Now uploading...');
  // uploadImg();
};
```

```html
<input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" id="imgPath">
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Why can't I do <img src="C:/localfile.jpg">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090712/why-cant-i-do-img-src-c-localfile-jpg). If your plan is to display an image before uploading to the server, that is not going to work. What you can do is write an "onchange" event (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) to your file selection input line (2nd line in your code), and upload it to a temporary directory and display it. As the user clicks on the upload button, you can make the change permanent. If the user cancels, you will display the default profile page.