# Angular 9 domSanitazer Not allowed to load resource

Tags: html, angular, src, angular-dom-sanitizer

I have application in Angular 9 and use DomSanitazer to build img url.
I get error:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/MyApp/Images/uploads/fbf8152f-ccea-45a2-b9a9-150cd4c421a5/mmm_3424.png
```

In component.ts I have:

```
import {
  SafeResourceUrl,
  DomSanitizer
} from '@angular/platform-browser';

  public avatarSafeFileUrl: SafeResourceUrl;
```

and when I load img:

```
this.avatarSafeFileUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.myAvatar.filePath);
```

In html I have:

```
<img [src]="avatarSafeFileUrl"  />
```

And I get error like above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I do <img src="C:/localfile.jpg">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090712/why-cant-i-do-img-src-c-localfile-jpg)

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand why I have to create browser extension? Where I should place img files to allowe them display in Angular? They have to be placed in assets? What in case when I need to store many gigabytes movies?

Comment: Browsers do not let you reference local files.  You will need to have them hosted by your web server some how.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I added staticFiles to Startup.cs and now it works