# I'm new to JSP & I'm making signup page but my firefox browser isn't showing the images, I'm using Kubuntu OS

Tags: html, eclipse, ubuntu, jsp, firefox

[html code no img showing, all permission to img are given, OS-Kubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGxl6.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I do <img src="C:/localfile.jpg">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090712/why-cant-i-do-img-src-c-localfile-jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to show your code in a text format rather than an image format, it is much more convenient that way.