# How to insert a img tag HTML to a specific element/div by python selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, webdriver

```
 img = "<img src='C:/Users/semnome/Desktop/21291010002.jpg'>"  //Path it's ok, it open if I try it manually on URL
 elm = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='content']")
 driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = arguments[1];", elm, img);
```

it's a local execution (chrome in debugging mode)

works to create the tag, but Image is not showing in browser (just img icon). What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think you'd need: "file://" before the path... bit of an XSS issue there, though... might have cross-origin problems..

Comment: for local file you have to use `file://` or `file:///` - like `file:///C:/Users/...`. But it may not work if load page from server because browser may block `file://` when it load data from server - all for security reason.

Comment: @furas  I try file:///C:/Users/ , so path blank spaces are not parsed correctly (path turns blue link before spaces). 

And results remained the same, images is not showing. it's a local execution (chrome in debugging mode)

Comment: as I said - if you run it on page from internet then it may not work for security reason - because hacker could use it to steal file with your passwords or your naked images. And as I said: `file://` or `file:///` - I don't remeber which version it has to be.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090712/why-cant-i-do-img-src-c-localfile-jpg