# HTML img access of another drive

Tags: html

I can't access a img of D drive inspite of giving full url in img tag

I have tried "." To access but after 2 dots it is not working

Comment: If you are publishing this to a webserver, this will break no matter what when deployed.

Comment: this is not going work; move ur image to local directory or upload it to a cdn and put the absolute url

Comment: Ensure you're using `file://C:/localfile.jpg` schema and that HTML is local, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090712/4536543

Answer (score -1):

D:\Staff ID Cards\Name_Tag_Front\nameTagFooter.jpg
Put this in your img src.

Comment: I understand the initial question was vague.  But it would be more beneficial to explain relative vs absolute pathing.